# Buliding VMware Automation Application for a project

Tags: api, automation, vmware, vsphere

I am trying to automate the process of provisioning VMs. Can anyone please tell me which language I should use and how should I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on which language your automation framework supports.  Assuming that you want to do it in `Java` .

Go through Steve Jin's [VI Java API](http://vijava.sourceforge.net/doc/getstarted/tutorial.htm). Its very easy to start writing sample programs to automate. Just download the `vim25` jars and point them from your java project. After that  have a look at this [sample](http://sourceforge.net/p/vijava/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/com/vmware/vim25/mo/samples/vm/VMpowerOps.java) for how to provision.

Let me know if you face any problem !

Comment: I am using power cli right now for writing these with xml. Do you know any site which can help me with this?